# Asp.net Core Role Expiration

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Is there a way to remove a user from a role after a given timespan? When I try something like the below code, I get a null exception once the Delay continues in sessionExpired()...

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PurchaseSession(PurchaseSessionViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Active");
    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);

    // no await
    sessionExpired(user);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}

private async void sessionExpired(ApplicationUser user)
{
    await Task.Delay(10000);
    await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, "Active");
}
```

Note, I understand why the exception occurs but I'd like to retain this type of role-based authorization since [Authorize(Roles = "Active")] provides the functionality I'm after. Is there another way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your `user` variable is local and thus is deleted after your first function ends.

You may use a *closure* (as a lambda function). It is a block of code which maintains the environment in which it was created, so you can execute it later even if some variables were garbage collected.

---

**EDIT**: If you want to know why my previous solution didn't work, it is probably because `user` was being disposed by Identity at a time or another, so here is another try:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> PurchaseSession(PurchaseSessionViewModel model)
{
    var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);
    await _userManager.AddToRoleAsync(user, "Active");
    await _signInManager.RefreshSignInAsync(user);

    // We need to store an ID because 'user' may be disposed
    var userId = user.Id;

    // This create an environment where your local 'userId' variable still
    // exists even after your 'PurchaseSession' method ends
    Action sessionExpired = async () => { 
        await Task.Delay(10000);
        var activeUser = _userManager.FindById(userId);
        await _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(activeUser, "Active"); 
    };
    Task.Run(sessionExpired);

    return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help. I just tried running this and it's throwing "Cannot access a disposed object"

Comment: @Phil_SO What object is concerned by this exception?

Comment: It's throwing the exception on _userManager.RemoveFromRoleAsync(user, "Active"), the object name in the exception details is "AspNetUserManager`1"

Comment: @Phil_SO Alright, try with my edit and tell me if it still doesn't work

Comment: Same exception. I suspect it's the _userManager object, given the object name. However, even when making a local copy of _userManager, the same exception occurs. I also tried this in addition to your edit as well.

Comment: Oh also, there is no User.Identity.GetUserId() method (not sure if you're referring to Microsoft.AspNet.Identity, not AspNetCore?), so I made a local copy of user.Id instead.

Comment: @Phil Yes, it may be `_userManager` as well, depending on how you get it first. If it is via dependency injection, be sure to inject it as *singleton*, instead of as a *transient* or as *scoped*.